# Non-linear approximation of an image of a geometry

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, edge-detection

I am trying to approximate different shapes of a weld bead geometry cross section in additive manufacturing with a graph or ideally (but not necessarily) a function. The regions are the outer shape as well as the individual layers. (see following images)

[image: Original RGB Image]

[image: How the approximation should look like]

Therefore, I applied some pre-processing methods to extract the relevant pixels which represent the geometry of a weld bead which are shown as white pixels. (see third image)
I derived this image with canny edge detection and multiple morphological operations such as closing erosion and dilation prior to that and of course converting it into grey-scale.

The "noisy" areas are the transition areas between individual layers of metal and only show up in this way, so in general there is not a "better" or "sharper" transition in thus less "noise". Pictures 3 and 4 are an example of some of the image pre-processing methods I used.

[image: Image preprocessing using global thresholding]

[image: Pre-processed Image (to be approximated)]

My main approach to treat the inner geometry so far was to split up the image in several sub-images and perform least squares regression on each individual one by interpreting the white pixels as data points. Afterwards I've stitched all those little approximation functions back together to form the image of the original size. I've tried it with different sizes of those sub-images. (see pictures 5 and 6)

[image: Approximated Image (sub-image size: 35 pixels)]

[image: Approximated Image (sub-image size: 100 pixels)]

However, this approach produces jumps between the functions as well as functions next to each other where the pixels or data points in my case should only be approximated with one function (see attached image). My next approach would be to use multivariate adaptive regression on the sub-images.

Thus, I'm asking if anybody knows a better solution for my problem, maybe even for an approximation on global scale without splitting the image into the sub-images. The approximation does not need to be a polynomial function, piece wise linear but connected functions are totally sufficient. I would be thankful if anybody knows a method that is at least capable of achieving what I want to do. Whether a pure non-linear regression method. Unfortunately I don't have many images (only 64), hence I don't think I can use an ANN. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

If you need to take a look at my code, just let me know. Thank you! :)

Comment: It is possible that your preprocessing destroyed much of the information available in the image. We need - the original images and - a hand drawing of the expected result. IMO, you are too far  engaged in an XY question.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, so I am not sure whether to post the answer here or edit my original question. Thus I am going to edit my original post so you could maybe have another look at it. Thank y,ou so much for having a look at my question!

Comment: It is possible that your preprocessing destroyed much of the information available in the image. We need - the original images and - a hand drawing of the expected result. IMO, you are too far engaged in an XY question.

Comment: I've updated my original post now: :)

Comment: Thank you, this is much clearer now.

Comment: This case is extremely difficult because of very low contrast and significant noise. Even a trained human would not give repeatable results. Reducing the image size will help a little, as can histogram equalization.

Comment: Yes, that is also what I am experiencing. I tried a multitude of image processing methods such as FFT/IFFT, global/adaptive mean and adaptive gaussian thresholding but the best result I got is shown in picture 3. I've updated my post again. All remaining pictures are taken with exactly the same exposure and of course the same aperture/focal lengths settings and in addition all specimen are manufactured with the same process and material. Thus, the resulting colour range in the histogram that represents the transition region on the inside would be the same, however quite noise.

Comment: Do you see any change to achieve what I want to do based on picture 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could obtain is with bilateral filtering for denoising, then adaptive binarization.

[image]

And on a reduced image:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that look so much better than what I've achieved with my pre-processing. I've used your image to predict the positions of each transition area by applying another method I'm working on, because my ultimate goal is to measure the weld bead height of each individual layer. It works so much better, thank you so much! I'm going to show you my results by answering my question.

Comment: Could you please post your code that produced this result? :) Thanks once again!

Comment: @PhilE: was made with a proprietary package.

Comment: Okay that's no problem, I will try out your recommendations using the cv2 library then. However, if I can't recreate your results, would it be possible to send you my pictures so that you can pre-process them? There would be in total 64 images.

Comment: @PhilE: er, if parameters need to be adjusted, this is at least an hour of work !

Comment: Well, after rereading your comment I believe I might have misunderstood your explanation. As I told you previously, all pictures are taken with exactly the same exposure and of course the same aperture/focal lengths settings and in addition all specimen are manufactured with the same process and material.Thus, the resulting colour range in the histogram that represents the transition region on the inside would be the same, however quite noisy. Therefore, the same settings could be used for all pictures.